# Unavailable to Export Data with Current Layout - Power BI Report Server

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

it is not yet available to export table with current layout from powerbi report server, because I had seen that it was supposed to be there in the release of Jannuary 2023 however it seems to me that it is not available yet.

Is there any possibility of doing it any other way ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> We have investigated this further and it is unfortunately not a trivial implementation for PBIRS due to some technical challenges. It has always been the stance that the Power BI service may get these features that are unique to them when using Power BI reports and this is unfortunately one of those scenarios.

If it is critical then we suggest using the Power BI service to do these exports.

This feature may come to Power BI Report Server in the future, but it will not be part of the May 2023 or September 2023 releases,

According to the comment of Microsoft employee, this feature may implement in the future, but not in 2023. They still need to overcome some technique issue.

Refer to [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Unavailable-to-Export-Data-with-Current-Layout-Power-BI-Report/m-p/3182047/highlight/true#M29457)

Comment: Please post a quote from there, into your answer.